# Inflating AlertDialog inside PositiveButton causes last dialog to not dismiss

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I'm trying to open 2 alert dialogs like permissions, the first one pops up and dismiss when I press the positiveButton, then It inflates the second one, but when I press positiveButton on second alertdialog it does not dosmiss and keeps showing it

```
 private void requestXiaomiBootPermission(){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        builder.setTitle("Automatic boot");
        builder.setMessage("we need this permission to work");
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                addAutoStartup();
                requestXiaomiBackgroundPermission();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).show();


        builder.setNegativeButton("Deny", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).show();

        builder.setNeutralButton("do not show", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        }).show();


        builder.show();
    }


    private void requestXiaomiBackgroundPermission(){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        builder2.setTitle("Popup window");
        builder2.setMessage("we need this permission to work");
        builder2.setCancelable(false);

        builder2.setPositiveButton("Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                addPermissionsOnBackgroud();
                dialog.dismiss(); // --> Here it does not dismiss when this dialog inflates
            }
        }).show();


        builder2.setNegativeButton("Deny", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).show();

        builder2.setNeutralButton("do not show", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        }).show();

        builder2.show();
    }
```

So the circuit is this

I open the app and the first dialog pops up ( `requestXiaomiBootPermission()` ) , then when I press the positiveButton **allow** it opens the second dialog ( `requestXiaomiBackgroundPermission()` ) but when I press **allow** on this one, `dialog.dismiss()` does not dismiss my dialog and keeps there, any solution?

Comment: How many times is `requestXiaomiBackgroundPermission()` executing?

Comment: just once inside that positivebutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't invoke `show()` after every `setXXXXXButton()` call. Just invoke it once, at the end. You're creating 4 boot permission dialogs, and 4 background permission dialogs, and they're all getting stacked on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening both dialog 4 times. Remove show() method after all three button.just keep show() method at end.

```
private void requestXiaomiBootPermission(){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        builder.setTitle("Automatic boot");
        builder.setMessage("we need this permission to work");
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


        builder.setNegativeButton("Deny", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.setNeutralButton("do not show", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });


        builder.show();
    }
```